# Navbar hamburger menu does not show the right li items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that has links: `Notes, About, Brand(logo), Founder, Contact`.
When I go to a smaller screen(mobile) and open the hamburger menu than only the 2 left li's (`Notes, About`) show up and the right li's(Founder, contract) just dissapears. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<nav id="topNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        ☰
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Dark Note Logo" class="logo"></a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Founder</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="row note-row">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Type note here..." class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 notes" id="main_panel"></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url("../img/curls.png");
}
#main_panel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 50em;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.note-row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.logo {
    height: 50px;
}
.notes {
    background-attachment: local;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to right, white 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(to left, white 10px, transparent 10px),
        repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    line-height: 31px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the right li's aren't showing?
Here is a link to my website[DarkNote](https://darknote.000webhostapp.com/note.html)

Comment: What are the classes `ml-auto` and `mx-auto` doing?

Comment: Can you create a snippet / demo? Thanks

Comment: I just did he didn't approve of it lol

Comment: Those two are bootstrap classes [link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: That snippet didn't work because I have the images on my pc and I dont use CDN's

Comment: I will put my site online so you can check it.

Comment: Just replace your images with placeholder images?

Comment: @sol I added a demo site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you must integrate all your `nav-item` , example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Dark Note Logo" class="logo"></a>
        </li>

             <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Founder</a>    
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" >
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li> 


    </ul>
```

after that you just customize position logo , founder and contact